# Are there any changes in the WebView related APIs in UWP or UAP Windows app?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10, uap

I am having a Windows 8.1 supported app, but now it is updated to the UWP/UAP (i.e. Windows 10) app.

After updating the custom URI scheme is not working, On a button click on the web page, we were using "navto://" custom URI scheme and handling were done in a js file. The button action was bind through the anchor tag.

From this approach, we navigate our web pages forward/backward or used to send a user to a particular web page.

But now this js file is being not called on the click of the same button and a System Popup appear saying "You will need a new app to open this navto link". For reference, please have a look at the attached screenshot of the error popup. If anybody is familiar with the issue, please suggest me the solution.

Actually I followed this page to migrating the app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/misc/migrate-apps-to-the-universal-windows-platform-uwp?view=vs-2015#MigrateCSharp

And also tried other options as well by googling but I haven't got any perfect solution yet.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: This is new [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) in UWP that you could compare the difference. Btw, do you load the local content with WebView?

Comment: Yes, seems like the local content is being loaded.